# Google Maps SDK for Android - Cost

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My question is about the charge in the Google Maps API, I have the following code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);
    Point point = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(sydney);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,16));
}
```

That returns a map with a marker and with a latitude and longitude that I'm assigning. My question is: Does it cost to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Maps SDK for Android at present time doesn't have any cost. If you check the price table of Google Maps Platform you will see that SKU Native Dynamic Maps (Android and iOS SDK) has unlimited quota with $0 price:

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#mobile-dynamic

However, Google requires a billing account with credit card information enabled in your project even when you use products with $0 cost.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Noowadays, each 1.000 requests in Android Maps SDK, unfortunately it costs a whole bunch of 7$.
Src:
https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Are you sure about this coz here in this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#mobile-dynamic it says $0 for for unlimited maps load requests.

Comment: It's only to load the map, but then it escalates a lot in terms of other services.

Comment: Hey @OneKe can you clarify more about "escalates a lot in terms of other services", what if I'm not using any of their services and just loading a map with a marker based on lat lang? My use case includes heavy user base.

Comment: If you only use the map loading and user's position, it doesn't cost anything. While using other functions such as geometry and custom routes generation, the cost arises increasingly.

Comment: It is NOT free. The web site clearly states that Maps SDK for Android costs $7 per 1000 requests. You do get a free credit of $200 each month, meaning that your first "28,500 map loads" are free. That's also explained on the web site. See https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/. So even just loading the map is not free.